# How do I find area of shaded area given side length relationship

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

[image]

Hi I was trying to do this problem but was unable to figure out how to find the shaded region

I tried to use proportionality with the shaded region but I still kept on getting the wrong answer

any hint/tips?

thanks!

Comment: Did you try computing it as the difference of two triangles?

Answer (score 3):

If the area of the small triangle $\Delta BDE$ is $a$, then the area of $\Delta BFG$ is $4a$, and the area of $\Delta BAC$ is $9a$.

$$20 = 9a - 4a = 5a$$
$$20/5 = a$$
$$a = 4$$

So the small triangle's area is $4$, and the shaded region's area is

$$4a - a = 3a = 3\times 4 = 12$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint...how many of the smaller triangles can you fit in the other spaces?